# mysql difference between orderby number and timestamp string

Tags: mysql, sql

**A:**
publish_time is (int) `2504698546'

```
select * from my_tbl order by publish_time desc
```

**B:**
publish_time is (timestamp) `2017-01-01 23:10:23'

```
select * from my_tbl order by publish_time desc
```

Which is more accurate?
In terms of **speed** and **memory** consumption and **CPU**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, any difference in speed is likely to be minuscule compared to the overall cost of doing the sort.  Second, as with any questions of this sort (pun intended), you should test on your system on your data.

Without an index, there is probably no faster way to sort than a 4-byte integer.  That would suggest that the first is faster.  There is one additional complication with `TIMESTAMP`:  time zones.  I suspect that the comparison of two timestamps is a tiny bit more complicated than for two integers.

All these considerations pretty much disappear if you have an appropriate index.  That is the real moral.  If you care about performance, don't try to do micro-optimizations such as choosing between two representations of date/time values.  Instead, think about things like indexes, partitions, correct data representation, and solid query logic.